# Создание адаптивных форм

Tags: html, css

Хочу на сайт добавить контактную форму, но не совсем понимаю как сделать плавающими поля формы (`input type="text"`), ведь у поля ввода есть фиксированная ширина (атрибут `size`)?

Comment: Вы пробовали давать полям процентную ширину (`width`)?

Answer (score 0):

Например:

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form >
  <input type="text" size="200">
</form>
```

Или с помощью media queries (раз адаптивная):

```css
input {
  width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 420px) {
  input {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<form >
  <input type="text" size="200">
</form>
```

P.S: Смысл в том, что даже если задан атрибут `size`, Вы можете управлять шириной поля `input` с помощью стилей.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже вариант, правильно?

```css
form input {display: block; width: 70%; margin: 15px auto;}
form button {float: right; margin-right: 15%;}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 450px){
form input {width: 90%;}
form button {margin-right: 5%;}
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="ИМЯ"/>
<input type="email" placeholder="EMAIL"/>
<input type="password" placeholder="ПАРОЛЬ"/>
<button type="submit">Готово</button>
</form>
```

И атрибут `size` у `input` - совсем необязательный, так же как и у `textarea` атрибуты `cols` и `rows`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Посмотрите какую-нибудь готовую CSS библиотеку, например
   [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) - самая популярная, как мне кажется.
2. size может быть
   задан в процентах от размера экрана.

Comment: Зачем человеку который еле в html\css разбираеться советовать всякие бутстрапы, у него каша в голове будет потом, да и от такого Г вообще нужно уходить, есть более изящные решения нежели бутстрап. p.s Smart-grid

Comment: Smart Grid? Вы серьёзно считаете начинающему проще освоить это чем Bootstrap? От неё вообще хоть какая-то документация есть? Я предложил может быть не самый легковесный вариант, но самый простой для новичка.